# Dynamically and performant call to add method on DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i would like to make a dynamic call on the Add method on DbSet that i don't know at the compilation.

Actually, it's possible with simple reflection but the performance are awful. Here is the code we are using now :

```
Type contextType = (context as Object).GetType();
var set = (contextType.GetProperty(entitySetName)).GetValue(context, null);
Type typeSet = set.GetType();
MethodInfo method = typeSet.GetMethod("Add");

Object[] args = { entity };

method.Invokke(set, args);
```

i've tried two others possibilities with different errors.

The first other is to use delegate

```
public delegate void MyDel<T>(T t,object entity);

Type contextType = (context as Object).GetType();
var set = (contextType.GetProperty(entitySetName)).GetValue(context, null);
Type typeSet = set.GetType();
MethodInfo method = typeSet.GetMethod("Add");

Type template = typeof(MyDel<>);
Type specific = template.MakeGenericType(childClassType);
Delegate test = Delegate.CreateDelegate(specific, method);
```

but on the last line, i get the following error : Error binding to target method

And the third option is to use expression tree like this :

```
Type contextType = (context as Object).GetType();
var set = (contextType.GetProperty(entitySetName)).GetValue(context, null);
Type typeSet = set.GetType();
MethodInfo method = typeSet.GetMethod("Add");


ParameterExpression paramo = Expression.Parameter(typeSet, "param");
ParameterExpression parami = Expression.Parameter(typeSet, "newvalue");
Expression convertedParamo = Expression.Convert(paramo, typeof(Object));
Expression convertedParami = Expression.Convert(parami, typeof(Object));

MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(convertedParamo, method, convertedParami);                    

Expression valueExp = Expression.Lambda(methodCall, paramo, parami);
Expression<Action<Object, Object>> dynamicExpression = (Expression<Action<Object, Object>>)valueExp;
Action<Object, Object> dynamicAction = dynamicExpression.Compile();

Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(otherType);
dynamicAction(o, entity);
```

But in this case, at the line "Expression.Call(convertedParamo, method,..

i got this error :

> Method 'DictionnaireONYX.Entites.ArticleSansFacturier
>   Add(DictionnaireONYX.Entites.ArticleSansFacturier)' declared on type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[DictionnaireONYX.Entites.ArticleSansFacturier]'
>   cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Object'

where ArticleSansFacturier is the DbSet.

Who can help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not clear what the various types involved are. Is `typeSet` actually the type of the set, or the type of the element? You seem to be using it for both at different points. It would help if you could give a concrete example of how you're trying to use this, so we could see the types involved.

Comment: Could this help?: https://github.com/maxbeaudoin/MagicDbModelBuilder

Answer (score 0):

I have to say I don't now how the performance is but after making a few changes to your code it seems to work. Especially the dynamic part at the end could give some problems.

I'v used a ModelContext with a Authors set in it.

```
ModelContext context = new ModelContext();

Author entity = new Author();

string entitySetName = "Authors";
string methodName = "AddObject";

Type contextType = (context as Object).GetType();
var set = (contextType.GetProperty(entitySetName)).GetValue(context, null);
Type typeSet = set.GetType();
MethodInfo method = typeSet.GetMethod(methodName);

ParameterExpression paramo = Expression.Parameter(typeSet, "param");
ParameterExpression parami = Expression.Parameter(entity.GetType(), "newvalue");

MethodCallExpression methodCall = Expression.Call(paramo, method, parami);

Type typeofClassWithGenericStaticMethod = typeof(Expression);
MethodInfo methodInfo = typeofClassWithGenericStaticMethod.GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "Lambda" && m.IsGenericMethod).First();
Type genericArguments = typeof(Action<,>).MakeGenericType(typeSet, entity.GetType());
MethodInfo genericMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments);

dynamic objectSet = set;
dynamic returnValue = genericMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] { methodCall, new ParameterExpression[] { paramo, parami } });
var action = returnValue.Compile();

action(objectSet, entity);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i tried your code but i receive an exception doing action(objectSet,entity) --> Microsoft.Csharp.RunTimeBinder.RunTimeBinderException : the delegate use some invalid arguments

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong. I've tested the code locally and it's working. Are you executing this code against an ObjectContext or an DbContext?

Comment: Ah! I think I see the problem. Are passing your entity as of type Object? If so, see if you can change this trough generics or do a dynamic dynamicEntity = entity and pass that to the action method

Comment: Great, it works. Unfortunately, the performance are as bad as with the reflection. There is another problem somewhere. Thank you very much

Comment: How do you test you're performance? If you cache the resulting action, wouldn't that speed things up?

Comment: I don't really test performance, i just use Stopwatch to know how long the treatment is. it's just the last statement that is slow, others are relatively fast.

Comment: OK. Try building the action, caching it and then execute it multiple times while keeping track of time. Then you have the initialization time (which you will do only once) and then execution time

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 4.0 you can use the "dynamic" keyword - that's the best and most performant way.
It will look something like this:

```
Type contextType = (context as Object).GetType();
dynamic set = (contextType.GetProperty(entitySetName)).GetValue(context, null);
set.Add(args);
```

I'm not sure I understand your code 100%, so not sure that's exactly what you are trying to do, but that's the general idea.

Further reading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i get and exception doing set.Add(...) --> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

Comment: This means that an Exception was thrown within the "Add" function.
Please check the InnerException property of this exception, and see what's the problem.
If you need further help, please post the Inner Exception type, message and stack trace.